# How to unpublish a web service using JAX-WS aadn bind to a different address

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, embedded-jetty

I've a JAX-WS web service deployed into an embedded Jetty server
I need to change the  IP address which is associated with the Endpoint

In order to publish I do:

```
Service service = new Service();

Endpoint.publish(address, service);
```

What happen is that when i stop and restart the server, the Service is published again and bind to the new address I provide, but I get a Warning like this:

```
WARNING: "GMBAL901: JMX exception on registration of MBean MBeanImpl[type=WSEndpoint,name=MyServiceService-myservice_servicePort,oname=com.sun.metro:pp=/,type=WSEndpoint,name=MyServiceService-myservice_servicePort]"
```

and if I query both old address (e.g. 127.0.0.1) and new one (e.g. 192.168.X.X) both are still answering (with two different instances of myService.
I wouldn't have this behavior, I want that the WS is unbound from the old address.

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find out that I simply need to create the EndpointObject, publish it, and when I need to restart that will be enough to stop ep (it will ensure that same ep will not be republished), than creating a new one and republish it.

```
Endpoint ep;
...
if (ep != null && ep.isPublished()){
        ep.stop();
}

ep = Endpoint.create(service);
ep.publish(getEndpointAddress(port, service));
```

till is better to wait half a second before restarting the server where the WS is published as sometime it stuck